# what is the format to encode to play video/audio file to play in different browsers

Tags: android

I am recording video and audio from android then i have to upload those files to php server.

Now my question is in which format i have to upload the recorded file to support all the the browsers to play the uploaded audio or video file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer really depends on how you're planning to play the files in the browsers.  If you intend to play them in a flash player, you can convert them to MP4 (AAC+H.264) or FLV.  If you want to play them using HTML5, then you need to have two different formats: MP4 (AAC+H.264) for some browsers and OGV (Ogg Vorbis) for others.

Comment: Is it possible to convert the uploaded file to flv using android

Comment: I don't think Android comes with required tools.  You can try getting a third-party library to do so, but you may be better off doing the conversion on the server using FFMPEG.  Keep in mind that a 2 minute video may take about 2 minutes to convert.

Comment: ok is it better to save the file data in server or database for perfomance

Comment: I suggest you save the actual video files on the server in the filesystem and save references to them (e.g. filenames, etc.) in the database for easy lookup.  I also suggest that you queue conversion - don't convert the video on upload, as it may take quite some time.